# Uninstall / Remove Ruby on Rails server Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, ruby-on-rails

Ok, I've looked everywhere for this answer and best I can get is replies like "Why would you ever want to do such a thing". What I want to do is uninstall and completely remove a rails server from my macbook pro. But as usual everything mac and uninstalling stuff is still a little new to me as I've been a hardcore windows user for all these years up until recently. That and I have found since I got my mac I rarely need to uninstall anything. Anyway. I figured I would give rails a go, see if its something I could get into, and its not I favor PHP more, and have truly no need for anything rails related other than trying it for my own sake of trying. Now I want to get rid of it, but I don't know where to begin. How can I do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework, /Library/Ruby, and erb, gem, irb, rdoc, ri, ruby, and testrb from /usr/bin.

Warning: OS X expects and sometimes relies on frameworks and software shipped with the system. It would be a very bad idea to remove the system Ruby. It might even get replaced next time you update OS X -- or it might not, but OS X might expect it to be there, and then bad things will happen. Remove it at your own risk. I am providing this answer because you asked, but I would not recommend removing a system framework.

[How to completely remove Ruby, Ruby gems on Mac OS X 10.6.4](https://superuser.com/questions/194051/how-to-completely-remove-ruby-ruby-gems-on-mac-os-x-10-6-4)

Comment: will that remove any/all dependancies of rails as well?

Comment: No it just removes the core rail pieces

Comment: No worries, just keep in mind there may be packages down the road that rely on some of those components, reinstalling is pretty easy if you decide to leave PHP for Rails =)